# Как сделать появление текста когда я навожу на картинку с помощью hover? См. описание

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, то что я написал в заголовке? Но, нужно чтобы картинка была добавлена с помощью img а не в css с background.
Тоесть просто вот так в html коде написать:

```
<div>
<img src="...">
</div>
```

Comment: Как я правильно понимаю, картинка должна появиться в блоке при наведении на него?

Comment: Да. Только картинку как в примере пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, в родительском блоке, где расположена картинка, можно разместить дочерний блок со свойством `opacity: 0;`. И при наведении на родительский блок, показывать дочерний. Ну как-то так:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 20px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.block img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.block__text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.block:hover .block__text {
  opacity: 1;
}

h3,
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><img src="https://sochinyshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Pushkin.jpg">
  <div class="block__text">
    <h3>ФОНТАНУ БАХЧИСАРАЙСКОГО ДВОРЦА</h3>
    <p>Фонтан любви, фонтан живой!<br>Принес я в дар тебе две розы.<br>Люблю немолчный говор твой<br>И поэтические слезы.<br><br><b><i>Александр Сергеевич Пушкин</i></b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет JavaScript. Добавим onmouseover='имя_функции()' в блок div.

```
<div ononmouseover="addImage()" id='test'>
  <img src='...'>
<div>
<script>
  function addImage(){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<div><img src="Новая ссылка на фото "></div>';
  }
</script>
```

Если нужно что бы удалении курсора все возвращалось на свои места добавьте onmouseout='новое имя функции()' в div и по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

Так ?

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item p {
  display: none;
}

.item:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x80" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, velit!</p>
</div>
```